# High Security Settings for All sites

Tags: security, settings

What is the main disadvantage(s) of using High security settings as default/all the time if you are mainly using Tor for reading purposes only.(Mostly texts)
Mainly the issue I only see is font rendering and image displays. Plus JavaScript are not really needed in texts, unless it is to make them fancy. But else, the texts can be still be read as per normal.

So it is a good idea, security and usability wise, to use High Security Settings all the time on your Tor browser if you are just going to use it to mainly read stuff all the time? [Also, I won't be watching videos, only images once in awhile.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disadvantages are that it disables some functionality, if security is a concern and you don't need the functionality then there's no real disadvantage to using the security slider at the 'High' setting.

The things you'll miss out on are things like site specific fonts (some iconography for some sites is provided as fonts and will result in [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) being diplayed instead since they won't be loaded), which could make navigation difficult. SVG graphics don't display and some mathematical symbols also may not display. Most of this is true for 'Medium' security aswell, with the main difference between 'Medium' and 'High' being if javascript is enabled at all or not.

If security is a concern and you do not need the functionality that 'High' on the slider disables, I'd recommend using the 'High' setting. Disabling javascript also defeats most fingerprinting techniques. There really is no downside to it if you don't need the extra functionality.